# Save data from an api call in MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, api

I have database table with the names of businesses and want to take advantage of some of the api's that are available. What I am wondering is how I could write a PHP script that would take my data (business name and maybe address) and process it against the api storing the resulting data in a mysql database.

I would like to in one script run all the business data in my database against an API storing it back in another table.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet...would love any direction you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a caching layer is a good idea to prevent unnecessary API calls, but I'd recommend keeping it out of the database, because then you'll be making a DB call which trades overhead A with overhead B. I'd recommend using Memcached or saving the API data in a txt file even.

Comment: That was fast...yeah for some things I would go in that direction but for this I need the data in the database.  Thanks for the fast reply!!